# How to get more Puzzle Panels?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, puzzle-swap

My friend and I both have a 3DS with spotpass and streetpass enabled. We pick each other up frequently. However, my friend has waaay more panels to get puzzle pieces from than I am able to see. I seem to be limited to the ones that come with the 3ds.

I got my 3DS much later than my friend did. I have beaten Find Mii though and have access to Find Mii 2. I just don't have any more panels to get pieces from. When I pass people, it doesn't even let me try and "Receive new pieces" because as far as my 3DS is concerned, I have all the pieces even though theres 100s more to pick from.

What do I need to do to get the new Panels to show up?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I didn't have Spotpass enabled specifically for the Mii Plaza. I needed to turn that on specifically as well. May also need to reboot your device if it comes up for anyone else, I did but I'm not sure if it's necessary.