# How to get more puzzle swap panels?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, puzzle-swap

I switched to a new SD card on my 3DS recently. Since then I've not been able to get puzzle swap pieces from anyone. I've tried updating my Mii plaza and it says I have the latest version. However when I street pass I my mii simply jumps into the puzzle swap world alone.

On the puzzle swap screen it says I have 105/105 of the pieces whereas I can confirm that I've passed my friend who has a panel and pieces I don't own.

I also have spotpass and street pass enabled for the app.

this is quite confusing, does anyone know how I can continue getting more pieces?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get more Puzzle Panels?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/138819/58396)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I managed to fix it and get all of my pieces back, good as new, without waiting for a new piece to arrive via Spotpass as many people have suggested on various sites.

It involves digging around in the file folders on the SD card, so be careful and pay attention to what folder you are in. You don't want to mess up your data, especially if you have downloaded games on your card.

First open the "Nintendo 3DS" folder. You will usually see two folders, one called "Private" and one with a long string of numbers and letters. Open the long-string one. Now you will see another folder with a different long string of numbers and letters. Open it. Now you should see three folders, "bds", "extdata", and "title". As far as I know, "title" is where your downloaded games are kept, so don't touch that one. **Open "extdata".** Now you'll see a folder called "00000000". Open it. Here you will have several folders that have names 8 numbers long, starting with 0s. Copy all of those folders, plug in your new SD card, and paste them into the same folder location. **Make sure you copy and replace**. I tried copying over only the missing data, but that didn't work. You have to replace every file (within "extdata">"00000000", not elsewhere. Again, don't touch the "title" folder) with the old version from your previous SD card in order to get your puzzle pieces back. Copy&pasting those folders, clicking "merge folders" when prompted, and clicking "copy and replace" when prompted is what solved this problem for me.

Good luck to everyone who encounters this problem in the future, and I hope this works for you too!

Comment: The easier version of this is to just copy the entire contents of the old SD card to the new SD card. It will work exactly like the old one did.

Comment: @Whelt - yes, if you don't already have content you wish to keep on the new SD card.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch to a new SD card, you can't get any Puzzle Swap pieces that are distributed by SpotPass until you receive one by SpotPass. Basically, you can't get any that are not available from the start until you get at least one puzzle piece from SpotPass.

The reason I know this is I accidentally deleted everything on my SD card.