# Why can't I get any new panels after moving Puzzle Swap to Game Vault and out again?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, puzzle-swap

I accidentally added Puzzle Swap to Game Vault on my 3DS. I have undone that, but I don't seem to get any new puzzles since then. When I meet friends who I know to have panels I don't have, I get to a screen which doesn't offer any option to get new pieces:

[image: Puzzle Swap Main Menu]

Any idea what I can do to repair the game?

I have seen [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/142846/187915) which seems quite similar, however, I didn't change the SD card so I don't have the old one to take files from. I have an old backup, but I'd rather not use it if it means to roll back the progress in all the games.